# JPA @Version - Why does optimistic locking not work when attempting to update a deleted entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

I need to prevent a user from updating an entity that some other user has already deleted. This is the desired behavior:

1. User A views the record @ version 0.
2. User B views the record @ version 0.
3. User A deletes the record.
4. User B tries to update the record. But User A already deleted so this should fail.

I'm trying to use optimistic concurrency control via @Version to accomplish this.

I have an versioned entity such as:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId", nullable=false)
    private List<Bar> bars;
```

`Bar` is not versioned:

```
@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

At step 3, User A requests delete. A transaction is created and `delete` is called on the `FooRepository` which implements the `CrudRepository`:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {


    private FooService fooService;

    @DeleteMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(Foo foo) {       

        fooService.delete(foo);
    }

    @PutMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(Foo foo) {       

        fooService.update(foo);
    }


 @Service
 public class FooService {

   private FooRepository fooRepo;

   @Transactional
   public void delete(Foo foo) {
        fooRepo.delete(foo);
   }

   @Transactional
   public void update(Foo foo) {
        fooRepo.save(foo);
   }
```

At step 4 sometime after step 3, user B calls update and

`fooRepo.save(foo);` will be called in a separate transaction

This results in inserting a new foo row into the database?!? `foo` is provided by the client and has the same id and version that was used in the delete. Since foo has an id, I thought it would try to update and then realize it could not because the entity was deleted from the DB. Instead it ignores foo's id and inserts a new record into the DB with a different id?!?!?!?

How can I get an `org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` to be thrown instead?

Looking at the `save` implementation `SimpleJpaRepository`, `entityInformation.isNew(entity)` should return false during update since `foo`'s id has a nonzero value. That means the entity manager should perform a merge.

Comment: Do you run those save/delete operations in transactions? Have you changed transaction isolation level somehow?

Comment: Delete and save operations are run in separate transactions via use of `@Transactional`. I have not changed the transaction isolation level. It uses the database default which is read committed.

Comment: Use soft delete